# Return partial documents from Node API querying Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Node API that is querying my Mongo database.

I'm able to return all documents within a collection. Now, I want to return partial documents.

My model (i.e. Player.js) looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Create schema for players
var playerSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        player_name:String,
        goals:Number,
        clubs:
        {
            club_name:String,
            season:String
        }
    }
);

var Player = module.exports = mongoose.model('Player',playerSchema);

// get all players
module.exports.getPlayers = function(callback, limit){
    Player.find(callback).limit(limit);
};
```

My application looks like this:

```
//...

app.get('/api/players',function(req,res){
    Player.getPlayers(function(err,players){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(players);
    });
});

//...
```

I'd like to query all documents within my players collection but return only player_name when I go to ".../api/players/player_names"

I thought adding the code below would work but it doesn't...

This on my model:

```
// [previous code]

// get all player names
module.exports.getPlayerNames = function(callback,limit){
    Player.find(callback,player_name:1).limit(limit)
}
```

This on my app.js:

```
//...

app.get('api/players/player_names',function(req,res){
    Player.getPlayerNames(function(err,players){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(players);
    });
});

//...
```

Comment: `Player.find(callback,player_name:1)` is syntactically incorrect should be something like `Player.find(callback,{player_name:1})`, furthermore you should be passing the query, the selectors and then the callback last. That or you can chain a `select()` onto the query and then invoked `exec()` to which you pass your callback.

Comment: Additionally if you want to add methods on this model you should be using static methods on the schema before you define the model. Eg. `playerSchema.statics.getPlayerNames = function...` and then using `this` to access the model eg. `this.find(...)`

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to Node & Mongo... I did the change you suggested Player.find(callback,{player_name:1}) and returns the whole document...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want something that looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Create schema for players
var playerSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        player_name:String,
        goals:Number,
        clubs:
        {
            club_name:String,
            season:String
        }
    }
);

//Its most common to pass the callback last, as this is what others do
playerSchema.statics.getPlayers = function(limit, callback){
    this.find({})
    .select('player_name')
    .limit(limit)
    .exec(callback);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Player',playerSchema);
```

Which will return results like `[{_id: ObjectId, player_name: "player1"}, ...]`.

If you want to return just an array of player names:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Create schema for players
var playerSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        player_name:String,
        goals:Number,
        clubs:
        {
            club_name:String,
            season:String
        }
    }
);

//Its most common to pass the callback last, as this is what others do
playerSchema.statics.getPlayers = function(limit, callback){
    this.find({})
    .select('player_name')
    .limit(limit)
    .exec(function(err, docs) {
      if(err) return callback(err); //first argument should be reserved for passing any errors

      callback(null, docs.map(function(doc) {
        return doc.player_name;
      });
    });
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Player',playerSchema);
```